# Animation suddenly not working upon incorporating Foundation?

Tags: jquery, css, zurb-foundation, css-animations

Before adding a link to Foundation, this animation to enlarge text on hover worked fine:

css

```
.enlarge {
        transition: font-size 0.5s ease;
        font-size: 2em;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

js

```
(function(){ 
    $('tr').on('mouseover',function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('sortableHeader') === false){
            $(this).addClass('enlarge');
        };
    })
    $('tr').on('mouseleave',function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('sortableHeader') === false){
            $(this).removeClass('enlarge');
        };
    })
})();
```

After incorporating Foundation, everything except the adding of the animated class broke. Any clue as to why?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('tr').not('.sortableHeader').mouseover(function() {
         $(this).addClass('enlarge');
    }).mouseleave(function() {
         $(this).removeClass('enlarge');
    ));
});
```

Comment: That code does the same task as mine -  it has the same effect.